# I don't trust vs I'm not trusting

Tags: present-tense, continuous

What's the difference between
I don't trust and I'm not trusting (anymore)
The present simple vs present continuous is obvious.
I just lack experience to build a number of examples with the continuous form. I just don't know what the shade of meaning would  mean.
What additional words would change the meaning, like, anymore for example.

Comment: The answer depends on context, which I invite you to add to your post. What **may** be going on is that *I don’t trust him anymore* describes the speaker’s **current** state and how it differs from an earlier state, whereas *I’m not trusting him anymore* may mean “From now on, I shall not trust him,” which describes what the speaker’s present state has become and, more importantly, what their  **future state** will be and remain.

Comment: Adding context to it, is what I was hoping for from other people. Now, from the present simple description I can understand, that it can mean not only action, but also a quality. For example, I don't trust people. It's not an action, It's a quality of my character. I do however completely fail to see the meaning of the present continuous form of it. I'd like to get more different examples from people.

Comment: If I'm not trusting him anymore, means I shall not trust him, than it's not present continuous anymore, it's one of the future tenses, using the ing form. That's my take. Please correct me.

Comment: *I’m not **trusting** him anymore* is equivalent to *I’m not **going to trust** him anymore.* Compare to how a parent might tell their child, *I’m not **giving** you any more potatoes until you have finished what’s already on your plate*.

Comment: To be present, *trusting* would have to be in a context like *At the moment, I’m not trusting him*. This (somewhat odd) utterance would likely imply that the speaker may have trusted him at some earlier point and isn’t ruling out the possibility that the trust may be restored at some future point.  But, again, that sounds odd. Much more natural would be *At the moment, I **don’t trust** him*.

Comment: It could be said during experiments in a garage. I'm not trusting this suspension. I don't trust wooden chassis in general, let alone a cardboard suspension. When you run it, keep you feet and hands away from it, I'm not trusting this thing.

Comment: But also, I could use present simple in this case, with pretty much the same meaning. Generally, people wouldn't be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Is there a question in your two most recent comments?

Comment: The question is, is it possible to say that, what I said. in short - I'm not trusting this new cardboard suspension of yours. Also, another question, does it make more sense to use continuous over simple tens in this case.

Comment: Another question might be. Who's that guy, who uses such language. Is he a southern hilly billy, or a new york journalist ?

Comment: As I’ve written in earlier comments above, whether it’s possible to say *I’m not trusting this new cardboard suspension of yours* depends on precisely what you wish to convey. It does sound odd for a present-tense meaning, though for some of them it could be okay. For a future-tense meaning it’s fine. If it has the sense of *I will decline any invitation to ride on it*, then it’s fine.

Comment: I've been aiming at present continuous. I want to describe a short period of time of not trusting. You on the other hand keep pushing it into the future, which makes more sense I guess. I'm not trusting your new tiger friend thank you very much... I'm not petting it. (future, mistrust directed into the future.)

Comment: I don’t intend to push anything anywhere, but instead to describe how the verb *trust* is typically used. If your meaning (and you are the only person who gets a vote on what you mean) is something like “During this present period, there is not taking place any trusting of him (or of his suspension or whatever) by me,” then by all means, use the present progressive. But be aware that because of the oddness of that message, you would run the risk of being misunderstood to be meaning the future-focused message.

Comment: What is it that inclines you to “aim at present continuous”? You could convey “a short period of time” with something like *Just now, I don’t trust him* or *At the moment…* or *For the time being…*. And there are probably other options.

Comment: a need for comparison simple and continuous aspect of the verb trust and finding what I might be missing.

Comment: Also, I heard it in Metallica song, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Looking to song lyrics as models of rhetorical style is notoriously treacherous.   In any event, unadorned, the sentence *I trust him* describes the speaker’s current, typical, or default attitude. *I am trusting him* simply doesn’t typically get used with a connotation of “at present.”  The verb *trust* simply doesn’t work like, say *phone*: *I’m **phoning** him* is perfectly idiomatic to express that the speaker is, at the time of uttering it, engaged in the act of attempting to establish telephone contact.

Comment: The **not trusting** form can express *intention-subject-to-change*:  *Since your sister got her drivers license only a week ago, I'm not trusting her to drive grandma 750 miles so grandma can visit your great-aunt in Chicago.*   There it is being used to mean "entrusting", sorta.  **don't trust** there would suggest that you think sis is likely to do something *intentionally*, like drive grandma to Florida instead, so sis can visit her boyfriend, whereas **not trusting** comports better with the view that you lack confidence in her driving abilities, given her limited experience.